# How to create a circular image without distortion in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to create a circular image but when it is displayed in the container I use the photo is deformed and it shows very badly

Use this code

```
Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: FileImage(photoImage),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

I also provided this code

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 40,
  child: ClipOval(
    child: Image(
      height: 100,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: FileImage(photoImage),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By very badly, I assume you're referring to the distorted aspect ratio of the image. You might want to use `BoxFit.cover`. `BoxFit.fill` is known to distort the image's aspect ratio as per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html)

`BoxFit.cover` ,on the other hand maintains the aspect ratio while being small as possible.

Comment: in the same way the image is distorted

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Circle avatar it is better
For asset images

```
CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: FileImage(photoImage), radius: 55.0)
```

CircleAvatar With network image

```
  CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: 
    NetworkImage('https://www.woolha.com/media/2020/03/eevee.png'),
    minRadius: 50,
    maxRadius: 75,
  )
```